# Passing a char * as function argument behaves unexpected

Tags: c++, c, function, char, arguments

I'm fiddeling with some general questions about c/c++ in perparation for an exam. One of these questions is to describe the value returned by function leer(char *a). I expected the function to return the number of whitespaces in a c string, but my tests showed that leer does in fact just check the very first char and thus just returns a 1 if the first element is a whitespace and 0 if not. It does not even iterate through the string but returns after checking the first char, while the very same loop inside the main function counts all whitespaces as I thought initially. I dont understand why they behave differently because the argument for leer is the same like the one I use in the for loop inside my main function. I assume that I lack of some pointer knowledge here but I cant figure out why my initial thoughts are wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

int leer(char *a)
{
    for(int b=0;*a!='\0';a++)
    {
        if(*a==' ') b++;
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{

char *a = "Dies ist ein Test";
std::cout << leer(a) << std::endl; //Prints 0   
int b;  
for(b=0;*a!='\0';a++)
    {
        if(*a==' ') b++;
    }


std::cout << b << std::endl; //Prints 3

}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with pointers. Look at the return statement.

Comment: Yeah, well, thats embarassing :D I was so focused on the pointer that I did not even notice it. Thank you for pointing it out I would have searched for hours.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are returning after the first iteration. You need to place the `return` statement after the loop:

```
for(int b=0;*a!='\0';a++)
{
    if(*a==' ') b++;
}
return b;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was so focused on the pointer, I didnt notice it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The two loops are not exactly the same. Notice that in `leer`, the `return` statement is inside the loop. That means it will return during the first iteration and never actually have a chance to continue through the string.

The loop in `main` however does not have anything preventing it from continuing through the string. The value of `b` is incremented and then outputted after the loop.

Your `leer` function should be written in the same way, where the value of `b` is returned after the loop.

Comment: Kind of obvious but I was so focused on the pointer thingy :D. THanks for the answer anyway .

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesnt work as intended is the return statement `return b;`. Its theoretically executed in every iteration, but practically of course just in the first one because after we executed it we arent in a for-loop anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would have searched for hours :D. Totaly didnt get it.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your main() you don't have a return... like in

```
return b;
```

This will exit the loop after the first iteration.

I propose you format your code for easier reading.

Comment: Yep, obvious once someone directs you to the correct path again. The original format in the task is even worse, it is this:      
    
    `int leer(char *a)
    {
 for(int b=0;*a!='\0';a++)
 if(*a==' ') b++;
 return b;
    }` 
I just changed it in my compiler for whatever reason.
So the correct answer to the question would be neither the amount of whitespaces nor if the first char is a whitespace. b is defined in the scope of the for loop and thus not visible for the return and the only thing this will return is a syntax error, right?